# Google Datastore limitation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wish to use Datastore, but I read that an entity size is limited to 1mb.

I have an entity "Users", which contains around 50k "User". I wonder if the entity size restriction is not too restrictive for my case. And if a day I will have more users, will I be blocked.

This is how I imagine my database, maybe I misunderstood how it's supposed to work:

```
+--------- Datastore -------------+
|                                 |
| +---------- Users ------------+ |
| |                             | |
| | +---------- User ---------+ | |
| | | Name: Alpha             | | |
| | +-------------------------+ | |
| |                             | |
| | +---------- User ---------+ | |
| | | Name: Beta              | | |
| | +-------------------------+ | |
| +-----------------------------+ |
+---------------------------------+
```

Where "Users" is an entity which contains entities "User".

Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for my answer, I somehow missed the "s" on your "users" entity :p.  Why do you have a master entity containing all your users instead of having a "user" kind, that can let you create as many distinct users as you want? (side not, how does your "users" contain users? is "user" an entity in it's own right and is linked by key to users, or as an ancestor, or simply a repeated field?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer :( I updated my post in consequence. Each user has around 40 fields...

Comment: Datastore has kinds (read as "table" from standard db), and entities (read a "row" from standard db). the size limit is on the entity, not the kind. So if you have a kind "user" containing multiple entities user, as long as EACH user is not over a meg, you're fine

Comment: I get it... I finally decided to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=528&v=fQazhzcC-rg

Comment: A pretty decent tutorial indeed :). I'll add some data to my deleted answer and undelete it then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "KIND" is user, your "entities" are EACH user. So no matter how MANY users you have, as long as EACH user is under a meg, you're fine.

The only limit to the size of the full "kind" is what you're willing to pay in storage. Reading up on [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities) doc, or watching this [introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=528&v=fQazhzcC-rg) could give some high level advice to your situation.

To better understand keys and indexes (another VERY important concept of datastore), I would suggest [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM) that explains VERY well how composite indexes work and behave :)